# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un arraylist de tamaño 50 y asignar a cada posicion un dato aleatorio?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

tengo un proyecto en el que tengo una clase en la cual tengo un constructor por defecto que me crea clientes aleatorios y tengo un metodo para rellenarclientes, entonces tengo un arraylist de tamaño 50, y lo que quiero es rellenar ese arraylist de tamaño 50 con 50 clientes aleatorios, pero no me funciona.
Aquí dejo mi código y gracias por la atención:

```
public void rellenarClientes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.clientes.size(); i++) {
        this.clientes.add(new Cliente());
        System.out.println(this.clientes.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Como estas? No hay nada aleatorio en el código de arriba. Agrega el constructor para ver qué hace. De todas formas no creo que dentro del constructor vacío deba estar la lógica para generar un cliente aleatorio. Me lo imagino como una funcionalidad del sistema completo, no del cliente por sí mismo. Puedes agregar la clase Cliente también. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

estas haciendo algo rarisimo en tu codigo

```
public void rellenarClientes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.clientes.size(); i++) { // cuando agregas clientes, el size de estos aumenta, si esto lo permite java probablemente sea un loop infinito
        this.clientes.add(new Cliente());
        System.out.println(this.clientes.get(i));
    }

}
```

por lo tanto si queres que tu lista tenga solamente 50 clientes lo mejor es:

```
public void rellenarClientes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        this.clientes.add(new Cliente()); //suponiendo que dentro se crean clientes con datos aleatoreos
        System.out.println(this.clientes.get(i));
    }
}
```

Si queres rellenar la lista sabiendo que tenes X cantidad y queres llegar a 50

```
public void rellenarClientes() {
    for (int i = this.clientes.size(); i < 50; i++) {
        this.clientes.add(new Cliente()); //suponiendo que dentro se crean clientes con datos aleatoreos
        System.out.println(this.clientes.get(i));
    }
```

De todos modos, no se que esta pasando en el constructor de cliente, asumo que ahi dentro se generan datos aleatorios